# About pairwise and mutual independence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If I have some r.v. $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ that are (mutually) independent and another r.v. $X_{n+1}$ that is (pairwise) independent from each $X_k, 1\leq k\leq n$. Does this make the vector $(X_1,\dots,X_{n+1})$ (mutually) independent?
If not, what else would be needed?

Comment: No it does not. One would need the new random variable to be independent of the whole previous family. (Wasn't this explained n times on the site?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, flip a fair coin twice and let $X, Y, Z$ be these Boolean RV's:

$X=1$ <-> first flip is H, else $X = 0$

$Y=1$ <-> second flip is H, else $Y = 0$

$Z=1$ <-> exactly one H, else $Z = 0$

then any pair is (mutually = pairwise) independent but {X,Y,Z} is not mutually independent.

Comment: thx, not happy about it, but thank's :)